# Get parent link for custom post type (Wordpress & PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a breadcrumb navigation for my wordrepss website and I'm struggling on something I thought would be easy.

I need to add a parent link (from a custom post type) to the navigation but it seems to be displaying a link to the page I'm on and not the parent.

Any help would be appreciated.

The code below spits out the following:

**Home > Current page > Current page** ?

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <a class="current-page pink_arrow" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>">Home</a>
    <a class="current-page pink_arrow" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->post_parent ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $post->post_parent ); ?></a>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($pageID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($pageID); ?></a>
</div>
```

Comment: get_queried_object()->parent if its hierarchical post type if you need archive get_post_type_archive_link() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_archive_link/

Comment: Not sure how to add that to my code, tried a few times and its not working for me?

Comment: You need to check if post have parent. Replace second anchor with  <?php if ($post->post_parent) { $parent_post = get_post($post->post_parent); ?> <a class="current-page pink_arrow" href="<?php echo get_permalink($parent_post); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($parent_post); ?></a> <?php } ?> also define global $post if you havent

Comment: Ok thanks, it's not displaying anything for the second anchor now

Comment: Could it be that the parent is in fact a page?

Comment: Post must be hierarchical if its page you need to pass the page id. If you want archive page then get_post_type_archive_link will get the post type archive page (which is not page but template archive-cpt.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your code is displaying a link to the current page instead of the parent page is because the $post->post_parent variable will only return the ID of the parent page if the current page is a hierarchical post type, such as a page or post. Custom post types are not hierarchical by default, so you need to check if the current page is a custom post type before trying to get the parent page ID.

Try something like this: (not tested)

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <a class="current-page pink_arrow" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>">Home</a>

    <?php
    if ( is_singular( 'your-custom-post-type' ) ) {
        $post_parent = $post->post_parent;
        if ( $post_parent ) {
            echo '<a class="current-page pink_arrow" href="' . get_permalink( $post_parent ) . '">' . get_the_title( $post_parent ) . '</a>';
        }
    }
    ?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($pageID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($pageID); ?></a>
</div>
```